# Inner Cupboard Drawer

Tags: kitchens, drawers

My partner and I have finally just bought our first house together and it is a 'period' house built in the 1930's. One drawback is there is no cupboard space in the kitchen and so at present the cutlery is just in a box.

I'm in the UK, anybody got any solutions? I was wondering if there is a way you can fit a draw to the 'roof' or inside the cupboard that you could just pull out when you have opened the cupboard door.

Bear in mind I don't want to 'bastardise' the kitchen and really a cupboard that has a 'push out' drawer would be ideal to keep with the feel.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, a person sure could install a drawer behind a cabinet door. However, "any ideas" questions are off-topic as too broad. Do a little research off-site, then come back with a more specific question about implementing your desired solution.

Comment: By idea's i mean any suggestions as to where I could obtain such an item then.

Comment: Shopping advice is also off-topic. Please have a look at our [Help pages](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

Option two is installing a cabinet organizer, which come in all sorts of configuration and materials and may be free-standing or attached to the interior of the cabinet. A web search for "pull-out cabinet organizer" stands a good chance of giving you some shopping direction.

Option one is consulting a local cabinet shop for suggestions and a quote. A custom solution is probably going to be price competitive with a high-end organizer while being exactly what you want rather than the inevitable compromises with premade solutions. At the same time you'll be able to explore all of your options, including replicating your current look on a cabinet with a drawer.

Answer (score 1):

I am a single guy who values function over form. I have very limited drawer space. I use the silverware holder out of an old dishwasher, I place it on top of my counter I place all of my silverware ( flatware )in it as if I were washing the silverware in the dishwasher ( knives point down ).  Right next to that on my counter is an old coffee can with my cooking utensils in it. Like I said function over form.  You could choose something more aesthetically pleasing him.

> What does period  House mean, was built in the 1930s but made to look like it was built in the 1880s.  I've just never heard the term period House before.

Comment: To me, a period house is a "style of house". That is to say it has the chacteristics of "Queen Anne", "Timber Frame", "craftsman", 1930's, etc.

Comment: Lee Sam is correct - period house is the style of house as in 1930's style so picture rails around the top of the wall, high ceilings, real wooden floors (not laminate), wooden roof beams. I guess it all depends on the country in question, in the UK (where I come live) a period house will have as Lee says 'Period' features based on when the house was built.

Comment: So it was not built in the 1930s but emulates a 1930's house ?  Or it was built in the 1930s and emulate a tutor or a Victorian or  craftsman.   Or It was built in 1985 to  emulate  and 1930s period House.  It's inconsequential really I'm just confused on your terminology  you said in your question " it is a 'period' house built in the 1930's"  when refers to a period Movie they are referring to a movie that is made today but is set in ancient Egypt  so when you said it was a period  House built in 1930 I thought it was a house built in 1930 in the style of another piriod.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try Pinterest.com. It's a great site for ideas. Go there and type in "drawers in cabinets". They're mostly for lower cabinets, but lots of ideas...